# Is there a way to just remove an element if it has no trailing siblings?

Tags: html, jquery

I was wondering if there is a way to just remove the `<h2>` element inside of an element with a particular class if that element doesn't have any other elements following it. For example if I have **only** the following:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="test">
    <h2>Test</h2>
</h2>
```

I want to just remove the `<h2>Test</h2>` but keep the div element present.

**jQuery:**

```
$(".test").each(function() {
   if($(this).children().length == 0) {
     $(this).remove();
   }
});
```

Comment: Elements, not tags. Tags are text in your markup file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter()` to select only the `.test > h2` elements which have no following siblings, and then remove them:

```js
$(".test > h2").filter((i, el) => $(el).next().length == 0).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <h2>This will be removed</h2>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <h2>This will also be removed</h2>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <p>Dolor sit</p>
  <h2>This will NOT be removed</h2>
  <p>Amet consectetur</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` to search for children elements.

Your current condition would prevent your from removing it since you're checking if there are no children. In your case, there would be children.

```
$(".test").each(function() {
   const h2 = $(this).find('h2');
   if(h2.siblings().length === 0) { //check for siblings
     h2.remove()
   }
});
```

Comment: `...if that div tag doesn't have any other elements *after the <h2>*`

Comment: This checks for _all_ siblings.

Answer (score 0):

If the `<h2>` is always your first children you can use `$(".test:not(:has(> h2 + *))").empty();`

```js
$(".test:not(:has(> h2 + *))").empty();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <h2>Dosen't Have sibilings</h2>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <h2>Has sibilings</h2>
  <p>Amet consectetur</p>
</div>
```